# how do I loop squares in a diagonal row in p5.js

Tags: loops, p5.js

I need to loop 9 squares in a diagonal row with small spaces in between. I'm not sure how to do this.

I've done it with circles before, but the code I used for circles is not working with squares

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
let boxA;
let curBox;
function setup() 
{
  createCanvas(800, 800);
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(3);
  noFill();
  boxA = [];
  curBox = createVector(0,0);
}

function draw() 
{
  background(0);
  for(let i = 0; i < 9; i++)
  {
    boxA.push(new Box(curBox.x,curBox.y));
    curBox = p5.Vector.fromAngle(QUARTER_PI, (i+1) * 90);
    boxA[i].show();
  }
}
class Box
{
  constructor(x,y)
  {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
  show()
  {
    rect(this.x,this.y, 50,50);
  }
}
```

I think this is what you're asking for. Idk, tbh. you were very vague with your question.

This code will start at 0,0 (the top left) and using p5.Vector.fromAngle, it makes a new vector from 0,0 to a new point given an angle and distance.

it then makes a new box at that new point. Simply repeat the cycle for all nine.